# How to loop through dates using for and while loops

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to loop through an XML file to find the earliest and latest date. Once those dates are found, I want to loop through the records again and compare the month and year from each record to the date that is being passed in. If the month and year match, then the count is increased by one. After the loop goes through all of the records, the date and count are added to an array, the date being passed in is then increased by one, and the loops runs again. The while loop continues to run until the date being increased is greater than the latest record date.

**MY CODE:**

```
        var record=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("record");

        var maxDate = 0;

        // Loop through all of the records to find the latest date
        for(var i=0; i<record.length; i++)
        {
            var tempMaxDate = record[i].getElementsByTagName("visit_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            if(tempMaxDate > maxDate)
            {
                maxDate = tempMaxDate;
            }
        }

        var minDate = 99999999999999;

        // Loop through all of the records to find the earliest date
        for(var i=0; i<record.length; i++)
        {
            var tempMinDate = record[i].getElementsByTagName("visit_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            if(tempMinDate < minDate)
            {
                minDate = tempMinDate;
            }
        }

        var minDateGraph = minDate;

        var count = 0;
        var data = [];

        // Loop until the minimum date is greater than the maximum
        while(minDate <= maxDate)
        {               
            var tempMinDate2 = new Date(0);
            tempMinDate2.setMilliseconds(minDate);
            minDate = tempMinDate2;

            // Loop through all of the records
            // If the month and year of minDate match the record then the count is increased  
            for(var i=0; i<record.length; i++)
            {
                var tempVisitDate = record[i].getElementsByTagName("visit_date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                var visitDate = new Date(0);
                visitDate.setMilliseconds(tempVisitDate);

                if((visitDate.getMonth() == minDate.getMonth()) && (visitDate.getFullYear() == minDate.getFullYear()))
                {
                    count += 1;
                }
            }

            var tempData = [minDate, count];
            data.push(tempData);

            var month = minDate.getMonth();
            var year = minDate.getFullYear();

            // Increase the minDate by one month
            if(month == 12)
            {
                year += 1;
                month = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                month += 1;
            }

            var tempMinDate3 = new Date(year, month, 1).getTime();
            minDate = tempMinDate3;
        }
```

The problem is when I run my current code, the browser crashes. I think I am running into an infinite loop, but I cannot find what is causing it. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: add alerts throughout your logic. you can have an alert count how many times the loop ran.

Comment: Could you add your xml file and maybe create a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem?